# $inc with multiple conditions and different update values in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a Products collection with data as given below. I am stuck with the requirement to write a single update query to decrease the stock of pId 1 by 2 and pId 2 by 3.

```js
{
    "category":"electronics",
    "products":[
        {
            "pId":1,
            "stock":20
        },
        {
            "pId":2,
            "stock":50
        },
        {
            "pId":3,
            "stock":40
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [the filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to define array elements matching conditions separately:

```
db.col.update(
    { category: "electronics" }, 
    { $inc: { "products.$[p1].stock": -2, "products.$[p2].stock": -3 } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "p1.pId": 1 }, { "p2.pId": 2 } ] }
)
```